# Regroupe all data on firebase for each "getKey()" when using them on app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a probleme and i don't know how to solve this.

```
userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot priereSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            //takeFromDataBase
            LocationUser locationUser = priereSnapshot.getValue(LocationUser.class);
            double longitudeD = Double.valueOf(locationUser.locationUserLongitude);
            double latitudeD = Double.valueOf(locationUser.locationUserLatitude);
            //createMarkerFromDataBase
            LatLng Test = new LatLng(latitudeD, longitudeD);
            String idNum = userRef.getKey();
            MarkerOptions optionsTest = new MarkerOptions().position(Test).title("Janaza le: " + locationUser.locationUserDate);
            map.addMarker(optionsTest).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
            //createLayoutFromInfoUser
            String adresseD = locationUser.locationUserAdresse;
            String dateD = locationUser.locationUserDate;
            String heureD = locationUser.locationUserTime;
            adresse_txt.setText(adresseD);
            date_txt.setText(dateD);
            heure_txt.setText(heureD);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

It's ok when the marker is getting the date and the hour, but when i want to show other information from the same getkey(), it's not working.
For exemple, when i'm clicking on the marker 3 for (12/07/2020), the app need to put the right information relate to this date on firebase from the same getKey, but it's not working.
the thing is that i don't know how to link all data from the same getkey()

Can you help me please?

Comment: "it's not working" is hard to help with. What happens when you run this code? Specifically: when you step through `onDataChange` in a debugger, which line doesn't do what you want/expect it to do?

Comment: my bad, i think "it's nor working" is not appropriate. The thing is that i don't know how to link all data from the same getkey().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but I think your problem may be here:

```
String idNum = userRef.getKey();
```

This gets the key of the `userRef`, which is the location that you listen to.

More likely you want to get the key of the specific user snapshot, for the current iteration of the loop. To do that, you'll want to get the key of the snapshot:

```
String idNum = priereSnapshot.getKey();
```

Comment: Yes !!!! that's it , but now how can i use this to get all same info from the key ? i've put a marker for each user location ,but for each user location there is some user information relate to user location, do you understand ? and i don't know how to regroupe all of these information.